# How to take animation time from Lottie json in Android?

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-jetpack-compose, lottie

At the moment I'm setting the delay as a constant, instead I want to take the time that is used in the json animation, how can this be done?

Here is code where i used constant:

```
val composableScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {

    LottieExample()
    composableScope.launch {
        delay(2000L)
        navController.navigate(viewModel.nextRoute) {
            popUpTo(0)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the animation code itself:

```
@Composable
fun LottieExample() {

    val compositionResult: LottieCompositionResult = rememberLottieComposition(
        spec = LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.splash_with_background)
    )
    val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(
        composition = compositionResult.value,
        isPlaying = true,
        iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever,
        speed = 1.0f
    )

    LottieAnimation(
        composition = compositionResult.value,
        progress = progress,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 12.dp)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took `compositionResult` out of bounds and pull out the `duration` of the animation.
Solved with next solution:

```
val composableScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    val compositionResult: LottieCompositionResult = rememberLottieComposition(
        spec = LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.splash_with_background)
    )
    SplashScreenAnimation(compositionResult = compositionResult)
    composableScope.launch {
        delay(compositionResult.value?.duration?.toLong() ?: SPLASH_SCREEN_DURATION)
        viewModel.destination.firstOrNull()?.let { route ->
            navController.clearBackStackAndNavigateTo(route)
        }
    }
}
```